# How to make font.draw update when the String does [LibGDX]

Tags: java, android, macos, libgdx

Trying to make a simple clicker that displays a number that increases with each tap/click.
The counter works fine but I can't get it to display a number that updates with each tap.
The System.out.print prints that the counter is working but the font.draw doesn't update with each tap. No idea what to do now.

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;
    Texture mario;
    int cash = 0;
    String money = String.valueOf(cash);
    Vector2 position;

    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {

        mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/mario.jpeg"));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        position = new Vector2(150, 150);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
            cash++;
            System.out.println("e");
            System.out.println(cash);
        }


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, money, 300, 260);
        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }


}
```

Comment: Hm, never had to use "String money = String.valueOf(cash);" Wasn't sure how it worked. How would you suggest making "cash" a printable String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You increment `cash`, but then never assign the new value to `money`. The simplest solution is to add a line `money = Integer.toString(cash);` or `money = String.valueOf(cash);` after incrementing `cash`.

Comment: I've done this but now the `String money = String.valueOf(cash);
` is giving the error "Syntax error on token ";", , expected" And when I remove the ";" the line `money = Integer.toString(cash);
` is giving error: Syntax error on token "money", delete this token

Comment: You have to do **money = String.valueOf(cash);** everytime you change its value.